# make: the system cannot find the file specified (Error 2)

Tags: c, linux, makefile, cross-compiling

I'm trying to compile a C program on Windows for use on a linux dev board.
When I try to compile using a makefile I get this output:

```
$ make
arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -g -Wall main.c -o filetest
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -g -Wall main.c -o filetest, ...) failed.
make (e=2): The system cannot find the file specified.
make: *** [filetest] Error 2
```

This happens whether or not a blank file called `filetest` is present or not in the same directory. If it is present, I can run `make clean` and it will remove the file.
Here is the makefile I'm using:

```
#
TARGET = filetest
ALT_DEVICE_FAMILY ?= soc_cv_av
SOCEDS_ROOT ?= $(SOCEDS_DEST_ROOT)
HWLIBS_ROOT = $(SOCEDS_ROOT)/ip/altera/hps/altera_hps/hwlib
CROSS_COMPILE = arm-linux-gnueabihf-
CFLAGS = -g -Wall -D$(ALT_DEVICE_FAMILY) -I$(HWLIBS_ROOT)/include/$(ALT_DEVICE_FAMILY) -I$(HWLIBS_ROOT)/include/
LDFLAGS = -g -Wall
CC = $(CROSS_COMPILE)gcc
ARCH= arm

build: $(TARGET)

#
$(TARGET):main.c

    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $^ -o $@

%.o : %.c

    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

.PHONY: clean

clean:

    rm -f $(TARGET) *.a *.o *~
```

I used tabs in my actual makefile instead of spaces for the code block above ^^
Also, I'm working within Intel's FPGA SoC EDS for a Cyclone V board.

Comment: Does it work if you run the command directly on the command line? `arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -g -Wall main.c -o filetest`

Comment: it says " bash: arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc: command not found " which I find really strange

Comment: Well there you go. You need to forget the makefile for now and go back to look at your development environment. You do not have the required cross compilers installed or if you do they are not in the PATH.